# Problems in storing the listview data

Tags: android, listview, twitter, hashmap

I want to implement twitter like functionality in my app as when you logged in for the first time you get the data from the server and show it inside listview but if you again open the app without logging out i do not want the app to request the server again for getting the same data so my question is where to store the data that fetched previously so app wont request the server again and for getting the new data i have implemented the refreshable list view so user will get the new data by refreshing the list.

And one more thing is after refreshing i want to store the new data as well to the same place where previous data was saved and i want to store only the 20 items to prevent the memory overflow . please help someone.

I have an arraylist ArrayList> fetch where i am storing the data while fetching from the server.

Comment: Save your items on a file when the user closes the app. Or maybe save the reply of the server into a String (file or sharedpreferences) and load them onCreate and reparse them.

Comment: ok, i will try to save the reply as string and reparse it

Comment: I am doing like this   String Store_json_in_sharedpreferences=new Gson().toJson(fetch);
           e.putString("ONGOING_DATA", Store_json_in_sharedpreferences);
           e.commit();    but cant it override this string with the new data when i request the server again ?? i want to store all the data the previous and newer one both

Answer (score 0):

The server must be returning the information in JSON or XML format, simply put it in shared preferences and retrieve/show later based on a few internal flags.

For example, here's a sample code to store stuff in shared preferences:

```
private void writeStrToPreferences(String strKey, String str){
        if(strKey == null) return;
        if(str == null) return;
        if(str.length() <= 0) return;

        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences(strKey, 0).edit();
        ed.putString(strKey, str);
        ed.commit();
    }
```

Reading back will also be similar and simple

```
private String readStrFromPreferences(String strKey){
        if(strKey == null)return "NA";
        if(strKey.length() <= 0) return "NA";
        return getSharedPreferences(strKey, 0).getString(strKey, "NA");
    }
```

For more, check documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: thanks for reply, but i am putting all of the json data into an arraylist of hashmap so how do i store this arraylist in sharedpreferences?

Comment: store it in shared preferences as a string before making a hash map out of it... right after getting response from server, put it in shared preferences... simple...